# Can avatars be the son of same God?

Tags: shiva, avatars, hanuman

Please explain why and how sometimes sons are considered as avatars of certain gods. In some tales, Hanuman is the avatar of Shiva while in others, he is his son.Please explain.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.Son of same God means?.Sri Hanuman is the 11th Rudra ,so he is Rudrangs(part of Rudra) But he is not a son of Lord Shiva.He is the son Pavan Devata.

Comment: @Rickross There are some folk story about Hanuman being sun of Shiva. He must be talking about that. I don't know how legit those stories are.